# Convert String to date (european to american)

Tags: php, date, format, date-conversion

I have a String on the form: "dd/mm-yyyy", where dd is day of the month with two digits, mm is the month represented with two digits, and yyyy is the year with four digits.

I need to store this in my database. Ive tried

```
$dato = date('d/m-Y' ,strtotime($_POST['dag'] )
```

But that clearly doesnt work. In my database the date displays as yyyy-mm-dd. How do I properly convert the String to the correct format?

Comment: On the database it must be formatted as a MYSQL date i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: out of curiosity: what kind of weird format is that even, where you mix `/` and `-`? never seen that one before.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann ... no format on Earth apparently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country ... maybe they're from outer space?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Its more common in written Norwegian, but I guess our official format is dd-mm-yyyy. I just wondered if it was possible. =)

Answer (score 5):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.strtotime.php) not accept your time string format, so it return false. You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` or `date_create_from_format`, manual [here](http://php.net/manual/zh/datetime.createfromformat.php).

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m-Y', $_POST['dag']);
```

check the [live demo](https://eval.in/713402)

```
<?php

var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m-Y', '11/01-2017'));
```

putput:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2017-01-11 14:34:53.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Comment: ... or `DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m-Y', $_POST['dag'])->format('Y-m-d');` to get it into the format used by the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `/` with a `-` like so:

```
$date = "02/04-2016";
$dateNew = str_replace("/","-",$date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat`:

```
$time = '12/3-1987';
$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m-Y', $time);
echo $data->format('Y-m-d'); //1987-03-12
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dbb7ae44175c8e893b6a2687cc63b435d7547835)