# PHP convert string into date time

Tags: php, string, time, timestamp

I have a php string from db it is `20/11/2017` I want to convert it milliseconds. 
It's my code to doing that.

```
$the_date = "20/11/2017";
$mill_sec_date = strtotime($the_date);
var_dump($mill_sec_date);
```

But it does not print any thing rather than

```
bool(false);
```

What is the problem and how can i solve it ????

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php for a list of supported date and time formats.

Comment: display milliseconds like timestamp seconds * 1000 ?

Comment: do i need to multiply it with 1000 ???????

Comment: Yes, because `strtotime` returns an unix timestamp, which is counted in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: but strtotime return false, how can i solve it first ?????

Comment: refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41571326/6521116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using slashes to separate parts of the date, PHP recognizes the format as MM/DD/YYYY.  Which makes your date invalid because there is no 20th month.  If you want to use the format where day and month is swapped, you need to use hyphens, like DD-MM-YYYY.

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = strtotime('10/16/2003');

$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
print_r($newformat);
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. if the solution solved your problem please do not forget to mark this answer as right answer.

Comment: @kousheralampranto if this solved your problem mark the answer as the selected answer for this question,

Comment: does it convert into milliseconds if i use "10/16/2013 10:20AM"

Comment: yup you can do like this, $time_ms = $newformat * 1000;

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime class to call function createFromFormat

```
    $date = date_create_from_format('d/M/Y:H:i:s', $string);
$date->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you got the date format wrong, see 
[here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) for a list of supported date and time formats:

> This section describes all the different formats that the strtotime(), DateTime and date_create() parser understands.

Answer (score 0):

You string is not accept by the strtotime, you can use `createFromFormat` set set the with the format type of the time string like below, you can also check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/881915)**. And you also can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41571326/6521116)

```
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', "20/11/2017"));
```